# Which Click event handler is to use when changing the content dynamically in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small application in jQuery, which takes the `href` value of an anchor element and inserts that as a div's Id. The div is a basic popup window which is only visible if it's triggered.

The popup window on gets triggered if a anchor tag gets clicked with the same `href` value as the `id` of the popup div.

**HTML Code:**

```
<a href="#i1" id="item1">Item 1</a>
<a href="#i2" id="item2">Item 2</a>
<a href="#i3" id="item3">Item 3</a>

<div class="popup"></div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var items = ["#item1", "#item2", "#item3"];

$.each(items, function()
{
    $(document).on("click", this, function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href   = $(this).attr("href");
        var length = href.length;
        var anchor = href.substring(1, length);
        var popup  = $(".popup").attr("id", anchor);
    });
});
```

---

**Problem:**

The popup window should be triggered once the client clicks on any of the anchors above. However it only gets triggered, on the second click. I guess the first one sets the Id and the second opens is, with the set value.

I have also tried to use another type of click event and it worked for the first click. The event, which have been working was:

```
$(this).on("click", function(e)
{
    // Stuff goes here as above
});
```

My problem is that I cannot use this type of event handler, because I will be changing the content of the anchor href's dynamically with jQuery.

---

**Question:**

How is it possilbe to make the original code working as I expect, so the client should only click once to the anchor tag to get the popup window? Anything else I should consider as well?

Comment: Noone an answer to this questions? Is it that hard?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#item1').on("click", function(e)
{
    // Stuff goes here as above
});

$('#item2').on("click", function(e)
{
    // Stuff goes here as above
});
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful. I have mentioned below the problem section, that this solution is not good for me, as I'll change the content dynamically. Next time, please read more carefully.

Comment: Careful, now.  We are unpaid volunteers, and we're not obligated to give you an answer *of any kind.*

Comment: @ Robert Harvey♦ Who said, that you're obligated? Noone. Actually, I have written the very same function above in another context and specifically written, that this is NOT working for me. So someone creates an answer containing a function, which is my exact problem, not the solution? Do you honestly think, it's a correct answer?

Comment: you are right i didn't read properly. Just keep in mind we are trying to help.

Comment: before i answer again, can you create a fiddle?